# rails custom validator doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, relationship, validation

I wrote a custom validator which sits in lib/readiness_for_completion_validator.rb:

```
class DisruptionTimeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    # if record.timeline.events[0].event_time > record.timeline.events[1].event_time 
    if true 
      record.errors[:Outage] << " end time needs to be after outage begin time" 
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is, I can't get it to trigger ever if I substitute the 'if true' for the commented out line.

I tested the condition in rails console and it works exactly as I would want it to, but it never evaluates to true in the validator...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I spent a lot of time researching this and this is driving me crazy :(

I have a Timeline that has many events. People can adjust event_time on events but there are two special events that each timeline contains that need to occur in succession.

Below please find what I have in app/models/event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :event_description, :event_time, :timeline_id

  belongs_to :timeline

  validates :event_description, :length => { :in => 10..255 }

  validates_with DisruptionTimeValidator, :on => :update

end
```

(I messed around with the :on but it didn't make any difference)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... my validator is correct, I was messing things up by sorting events in my controller and then saving the Timeline... so as new events were being added up events[0] and events[1] were getting replaced by other events...